# Can Jekyll order posts according to the Front matter

Tags: jekyll

So if the date is in the frontmatter, Can Jekyll use this data to order posts??

Could you have multiple ways of ordering post based on whats in the frontmatter???

Answer (score 4):

```
{% assign sortedPosts = site.post | sort: 'date' %}
```

or

```
{% assign sortedPosts = site.posts | sort: 'anyFrontMatterVariable' %}
```

you can now loop like `{% for post in sortedPosts %}`
    ...

Note : Sorting in the loop like `{% for post in site.posts | sort: 'date' %}`doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Beside `date` there is a way of ordering post based on whats in the YAML Front Matter

> Add `weight` in the YAML Front Matter of your posts

post #1

```
---
...
weight: 1
---
```

post #2

```
---
...
weight: 2
---
```

Then sort them like this:

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | sort: 'weight' %}
{% for post in posts %}
  ..your code
{% endfor %}
```